# Can I connect to a VPN over iPhone hotspot-provided wifi?

Tags: vpn, iphone

Using windows 10, with SonicWALL Global VPN Client.

Some preferences:
Preferred DNS 192.168.1.50
Alternate DNS 192.168.1.101

Comment: I'm also connecting via LTE

Comment: What steps have you tried? What makes you think you can't?